# C++ - FFmpeg Ogg/Vorbis-Decoding

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decoding, ogg, oggvorbis

I want to decode some audio streams in the format ogg/vorbis. I already found an example of MP3 and MP2 decoding here: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html at line 236.
But this code doesn't work for files in the format ogg/vorbis. I only want the raw data, so the decoding from ogg/vorbis into raw data, but i don't find anything. Anyone here with help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mp3 does not require demuxing. oog does. You muse demux using something like avformat av_read_packet(). The dranger.com tutorial is probably a good place to start.